# Electron how can I open a new window from a link <a> tag

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, window, electron

I am kind of new to Electron/Js and I'm having trouble creating this piece of code. I have an ordinary menu [ Home, Topic1, Topic2, Calculator...etc. ] and I'm trying to open a new window when the user clicks on "Calculator" in the menu. I have created the window and used the property "show: false;" but I can't figure out how to "wire it up" to make the link to send a signal and execute "altWindow.show()" for example. I have been looking quite a bit in the Electron docs and I just can't figure it out. I did try with event listeners but something doesn't work quite right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open a new window you need to get the main process to change show to `true` for the window you've created.

In your renderer process (the main window) use [ipcRenderer](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-renderer/) to send a message to the main process.

In the Main process use [ipcMain](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-main/) to listen for the event and in the attached handler update your second window to show `true`.

**Renderer**

```
buttonClicked(e){
  e.preventDefault()

  ipcRenderer.send('open-calc')
}
```

**Main**

```
ipcMain.on('open-calc', function(){
    calcWindow.show() // Assuming that your calculator window is the variable calcWindow
})
```